# Facing issue in updating decimal value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const tokenAttributeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    wallet: { type: String, required: true },
    token_id: { type: Number, required: true },
    token_uri: { type: String, required: true },
    attributes: {
        fuel: {
            value: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
            maxValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
        },
        mine: {
            value: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
            maxValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
        },
        durability: {
            value: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
            maxValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
        },
        luck: {
            value: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
            maxValue: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
                set: setTwoDecimals,
                get: getTwoDecimals,
            },
        },
    },
    totalDistance: { type: Schema.Types.Decimal128, default: 0 },
    cardType: { type: String },
    cardLevel: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },

    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

function setTwoDecimals(num) {
    if (typeof num !== 'number') {
        return num;
    }
    return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
}

function getTwoDecimals(num) {
    if (typeof num !== 'number') {
        return num;
    }
    return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('TokenAttribute', tokenAttributeSchema);
```

```
*Cron Job:*
const cron = require("node-cron");
const TokenAttribute = require("../models/TokenAttribute");
const CardLevel = require("../models/CardLevel");

const attributeNames = ["fuel", "mine", "durability", "luck"];

const updatedValues = (collection, attributes) => {
    const update = {
        $set: {},
    };

    attributeNames.forEach((attribute) => {
        const updatedAttributeValue = parseFloat(
            (collection.attributes[attribute]?.value + attributes[attribute]).toFixed(2)
        );

        update.$set[`attributes.${attribute}.maxValue`] = parseFloat(
            (collection.attributes[attribute]?.maxValue + attributes[attribute]).toFixed(2)
        );

        if (collection.attributes[attribute].value > collection.attributes[attribute]?.maxValue) {
            update.$set[`attributes.${attribute}.value`] = collection.attributes[attribute]?.maxValue;
        } else {
            update.$set[`attributes.${attribute}.value`] = updatedAttributeValue;
        }
    });

    update.$set["cardLevel"] = attributes.cardLevel;

    return update;
};


cron.schedule("*/10 * * * * *", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const currentTime = new Date();
        let updateAttributes = {};
        const collection = await CardLevel.find({});

        if (collection.length === 0) {
            console.log("No data found in CardLevel collection");
            return;
        } else {
            for (const card of collection) {
                console.log("Card Level Updated Time:", card.cardLevelUpdatedTime);

                if (currentTime > card.cardLevelUpdatedTime) {
                    const tokenAttribute = await TokenAttribute.findOne({
                        token_id: card.tokenId,
                    });

                    if (card.cardLevel != tokenAttribute.cardLevel) {
                        const attributes = attributeNames.reduce((acc, attribute) => {
                            acc[attribute] =
                                attribute === "mine" ? 0.1 : card.cardLevel - tokenAttribute.cardLevel;
                            return acc;
                        }, {});
                        attributes.cardLevel = Number(card.cardLevel);

                        if (card.cardLevel > 1) {
                            updateAttributes = updatedValues(tokenAttribute, attributes);
                        } else {
                            updateAttributes = {
                                $set: {
                                    cardLevel: attributes.cardLevel,
                                },
                            };
                        }

                        console.log(updateAttributes);
                        const update = await TokenAttribute.updateOne(
                            { _id: tokenAttribute._id },
                            updateAttributes
                        );

                        if (update) {
                            await CardLevel.findOneAndDelete({
                                tokenId: tokenAttribute.token_id,
                            });
                        }

                        console.log("Attributes and Level Updated Successfully");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("No time matched data found");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
});
```

I'm encountering an issue where attributes like fuel, durability, and luck are increasing by 1 for each level up, which is the expected behaviour. However, the "mine" attribute value is supposed to increase by 0.1 for each level up. The other attributes (fuel, durability, and luck) are functioning correctly and increasing by 1 for every level gained. The "mine" attribute's value initially increases as expected, even reaching the desired value of 1.8 when the level reaches 9.

However, after some time, I noticed that the "mine" attribute's value and its corresponding "maxValue" revert back to 1.4. This behaviour is unexpected and not consistent with the intended functionality. I have reviewed both the schema definition and the cron job code, and everything appears to be set up correctly.

I suspect there might be a logical issue or a race condition in the cron job or a potential interaction with other parts of the codebase that could be causing this behaviour. I'm seeking guidance on what might be causing the "mine" attribute value to revert back to 1.4 after reaching 1.8, despite the intended logic.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!